# Affdex 'opencv-webcam-demo' Crashes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, ubuntu-16.04, affdex-sdk

I made a program that was based off of the demo program on the affdex git page found [here](https://github.com/Affectiva/cpp-sdk-samples). It is the demo called 'opencv-webcam-demo'. I was running Ubuntu 14.04 at the time and it worked fine. I then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and now the demo (even without my changes) does not run properly. I tried to install the latest versions of opencv and boost and confirmed that they were installed correctly but I still get the same issue.

Here is the output when I run the program in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
ethan@ethan-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/leepsProgram/build/opencv-webcam-demo$ ./opencv-webcam-demo --help
Hit ESCAPE key to exit app..
Encountered an exception std::exception*** Error in `./opencv-webcam-demo': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001c71ca8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f0ce2798725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f0ce27a0f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f0ce27a4abc]
./opencv-webcam-demo(_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathD1Ev+0x18)[0x469c86]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9a)[0x7f0ce275b35a]
/home/ethan/libraries/affdex-sdk/lib/libaffdex-native.so(+0x5273a3)[0x7f0ce642a3a3]
```

There was also a  Memory Map so if that helps then let me know and I can paste that in here too.

So far I have tried to figure out what part of the code works and what part does not work and found that if you remove boost from the program it will reach up until the point were Affdex has to specify a path to the data folder, at which point it throws an Affdex Exception saying that the data path must be non-null. However it should not be null because I set it at the start.

```
affdex::path DATA_FOLDER = "<path to data folder>";
...
frameDetector->setClassifierPath(DATA_FOLDER);
```

Still, removing boost is not ideal since it is already coded for me. But if I have to remove boost then I must solve this issue as well.

Libraries and their versions / OS version:

- Boost 1.59.0
- OpenCV 3.1.0
- Affdex 3.1-396
- Ubuntu 16.04

Are these libraries compatible with Ubuntu 16.04?

Thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are mixing libraries with compiled with incompatible versions of libstdc++ .. What is the compiler version you are using?

The current version of the linux SDK was compiled with GCC 4.8

Comment: I am using cmake version 3.5.1

Comment: I have similar problem, with similar error log. Please consider to upgrade or find a better way to the C++ samples version. Many people try to use the same C++ code for testing. I wasted a lot of time to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: I have solved this problem by updating SDK version to the newest version (https://download.affectiva.com/linux/gcc-5.4/affdex-cpp-sdk-4.0-75-ubuntu-xenial-xerus-x86_64bit.tar.gz).

The tutorial provided the old version:

```
wget https://download.affectiva.com/linux/affdex-cpp-sdk-3.2-20-ubuntu-xenial-xerus-64bit.tar.gz
```

I have similar problem, with similar error log. Please consider to upgrade or find a better way to the C++ samples version. Many people try to use the same C++ code for testing. I wasted a lot of time to figure out why?

```
Debugging starts
Hit ESCAPE key to exit app..
Initializing Affdex FrameDetector
*** Error in `/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/cpp-sdk-samples/build/opencv-webcam-demo/opencv-webcam-demo': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000856e10 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ffff582c7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7ffff5839698]
/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/cpp-sdk-samples/build/opencv-webcam-demo/opencv-webcam-demo(_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathD1Ev+0x18)[0x467948]
/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/affdex-sdk/lib/libaffdex-native.so(_ZN6affdex12DetectorBase17setClassifierPathERKSs+0xc6)[0x7ffff6f5061a]
/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/affdex-sdk/lib/libaffdex-native.so(_ZN6affdex8Detector17setClassifierPathERKSs+0x2f)[0x7ffff6f4abb1]
/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/cpp-sdk-samples/build/opencv-webcam-demo/opencv-webcam-demo(main+0xaed)[0x466110]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ffff57d5830]
/home/aiq/Desktop/aiq_workspace/cpp-sdk-samples/build/opencv-webcam-demo/opencv-webcam-demo(_start+0x29)[0x465209]
```

Please look into the issue. Comments not taking long answer, so I post as an answer here.